# Rails 3 - Calendar Date Select Gem - Disable Field Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using `gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'git://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'` in my Gemfile.

Is there an option for disabling the user from keying in the date, forcing them to use the popup calendar?  For some reason, if they key in the date by hand, the wrong date is stored.

Here it is on my form:

```
<%= f.calendar_date_select "invoice_date", :index => '1', :time => false, :size => 12 %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, as soon as I submitted the question, I figured it out:

```
:popup => "force"
```